# django_filters search on field in ManyToMany through model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a manytomany relationship with a through model (joint table). I'd like to utilize the [`search_fields`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) in DRF or other custom Filter to filter on a field in the **through** model.

model 1:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    ein_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=False)
    record_keepers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'record_keepers.RecordKeepers', through='record_keepers.CompanyRecordKeepers',
        related_name='record_keepers')
```

model 2 (through model):

```
class CompanyRecordKeepers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    filing_year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey('employers.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                blank=True, null=False)
    record_keeper = models.ForeignKey('RecordKeepers', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=False)
```

model 3:

```
class RecordKeepers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now in my view, I'd like to search for companies who filed in the `filing_year` 2019 and whose `record_keeper` name is contains `some_value`

View:

```
class ListCompanyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ['companyrecordkeepers__filing_year']
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
```

Ideally I could do a GET request with some params to filter on:

`?companyrecordkeepers__filing_year=2019&name=some_value`

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a related_name you need to add the suffix `_set` whenever querying a reverse relation. Also, a `SearchFilter` is for simple single query parameter so for your case it's better to define them as `filterset_fields`. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters

```
class ListCompanyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['companyrecordkeepers_set__filling_year', 'name']
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: companyrecordkeepers_set__filing_year`